# Docker multi stage build fails random

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-multi-stage-build

This quite plain multistage build fails **randomly** (9 out of 10) with message:

```
Step 13/14 : COPY --from=builder /ng-app/target/www .
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/715082a9428418b33c27286a12e89539ef6580392eeb015d509c0f77fee1d8a2/merged/ng-app/target/www: no such file or directory
```

Dockerfile:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###

# We label our stage as 'builder'
FROM node:8-alpine as builder

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python libnotify git openssh

COPY .yo-rc.json package.json yarn.lock bower.json gulpfile.js /
COPY src/ /src
COPY gulp/ /gulp

RUN npm set progress=false && npm config set depth 0 && yarn cache clean --force

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm installs at each build

## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder
RUN yarn install --no-progress && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules /ng-app

COPY . .

### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY docker/httpd/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/target/www .

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Docker version is: `Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a`
Kernel: `4.15.0-33-generic`
OS: `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`